# NSCollectionView renders all NSCollectionViewItems at the same point

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I am trying to create a simple `NSCollectionView` programmatically. I am setting it up in the `NSViewController`:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var scrollView: NSScrollView!
    var collectionView: NSCollectionView!
    override func loadView() {
        self.view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 400))
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView = NSCollectionView(frame: NSZeroRect)
        collectionView.backgroundView?.wantsLayer = true
        collectionView.backgroundColors = [NSColor.black]
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.register(CollectionViewItem.self, forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("CollectionViewItem"))
        scrollView = NSScrollView(frame: view.frame)
        scrollView.documentView = collectionView
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSCollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("CollectionViewItem"), for: indexPath)
        item.representedObject = indexPath.item
        return item
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSSize {
        return NSSize(width: 25, height: 25)
    }
}
```

Here's how I am setting up the `NSCollectionViewItem`:

```
class CollectionViewItem: NSCollectionViewItem {
    var collectionViewItemView: CollectionViewItemView?
    override func loadView() {
        if (self.representedObject != nil) {
            self.collectionViewItemView = CollectionViewItemView(frame: NSZeroRect, number: self.representedObject as! Int)
            self.view = collectionViewItemView!
        } else {
            self.view = CollectionViewItemView(frame: NSZeroRect)
        }
    }
    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            loadView()
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm creating a custom `NSView` to work inside the `NSCollectionViewItem`:

```
class CollectionViewItemView: NSView {
    var number: Int?
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }
    convenience init(frame frameRect: NSRect, number: Int) {
        self.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.number = number
        layoutSubviews()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    func layoutSubviews() {
        let label = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 60, 30))
        label.stringValue = "\(self.number!)"
        addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

Now, despite the fact that I am using an `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout`, conforming to the `NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and providing a `sizeForItemAt` all indices, the resultant `CollectionViewItemView` is always sized 0, as shown below:

[image: NSCollectionView]

In sample projects online, the authors always feed an `NSZeroRect` to the frame of the `NSCollectionViewItem`. If I give it a custom `NSRect`, it always renders them on top of each other (since the origin of the frame is always the same).

What is the proper way of doing this? I'm at a loss. Why is the `NSCollectionView` not responding to the `NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen this problem, but here's a guess:

In `CollectionViewItem` you are overriding `loadView()` but it never calls `super.loadView()`. `CollectionViewItem` is a subclass of `NSViewController` and if you override `loadView()` you must first invoke `super.loadView()` so the view controller can initialize its internal state.

If you're going to be targeting macOS 10.10 and later, you probably want to override `viewDidLoad()` instead.